# Using SFDX, getting "The package root directory is not a source directory." when converting source to metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Tried to run this command:

```
sfdx force:source:convert -r ./ -d mdapioutput
```

from my project root, and got this error:

The package root directory is not a source directory

Comment: Just want to note that the same exception is thrown if you mistakenly run sfdx force:source:convert from the wrong directory. If you don't immediately realize this, it can be very opaque to debug.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem, when I wanted to create a temporary (git cloned) copy and use this copy to be wrapped and deployed. I always got the error, even for the cloned `force-app` directory.

You fix this, when you add a second entry in the packageDirectories inside the `sfdx-project.json` file

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "temp-deployment/force-app",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

I did not stick with this approach, but this way you can have two source directories and select one of them.

Answer (score 3):

It's intuitive to run this command from the project root, but what this command does is look inside your sfdx-project.json file, and the default value there points to the force-app directory.

So the command that will work is:

```
sfdx force:source:convert -r ./force-app/ -d mdapioutput
```

For more info, see:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_convert_mdapi.htm